# How can I print a really long number?

Tags: python, pi

I want to print the value of an irrational number, like pi. I want to print as many decimal places as possible.

Comment: Finding all the decimal numbers in Pi, is a research project.

Comment: I would think that before worrying about *printing* pi, you should worry about determining its actual value. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is :)

If you want `PI` itself look here : http://thelivingpearl.com/2013/05/28/computing-pi-with-python/

In general you can use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library, for achieving more decimal points.

Note: Python uses `float` as default and it has it's type specific limitations